# Linphone android crash "Cannot start linphone"

Tags: java, android, linphone

I'm working on an android application using Linphone in order to make calls through this library.

I've downloaded this : http://www.linphone.org/technical-corner/liblinphone/downloads (Liblinphone Android version 2.4.0)

I've added it to the libs folder of my android project, it is present in the project java build path.

But when I launch the app on my device, I've got this error log :

```
Cannot start linphone
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060002
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1125)
at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1040)
at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1017)
at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.copyFromPackage(LinphoneManager.java:569)
at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.copyAssetsFromPackage(LinphoneManager.java:555)
at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.startLibLinphone(LinphoneManager.java:443)
at org.linphone.LinphoneManager.createAndStart(LinphoneManager.java:208)
```

Any idea why this error is raised ? I should miss something but I can't find it ...

Thanks !

EDIT : I've not said that I'm using this linphone.jar in a Cordova plugin.

Comment: Looking [here](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric-gradle-plugin/issues/110) it seems that it may be an issue with using Gradle and/or Android Studio vs Eclipse w/ Android SDK. Which environment are you using?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse with Android SDK. I thought that it is a linphone integration problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself, I'm gonna explain what I've done. Maybe it could be help someone in the future :)

First, I've had not added all .so files needed for the liblinphone in the libs directory of the android project.After adding these files, it was better, the android app found the lib.

Then, I tried to use LinphoneService and LinphoneManager (of the lib), but these classes require some resources that I didn't have. Anyway, this was not a good way to use the liblinphone.
I've reuse the basic features of LinphoneCore (used in LinphoneService / LinphoneManager) in my own android service : registration, listeners ... as described on this page : [Liblinphone java interface](http://www.linphone.org/docs/liblinphone-javadoc/)

Now it builds correctly, and all my features work like a charm !

Comment: Does every SIP function works correctly after you reuse `LinphoneCore`?

Comment: Yes ! You just need to "copy" the LinphoneManager/Service behaviour !

Answer (score -3):

@bastien,
Please install linphone from playstore.

I had installed on many android devices.
It works nicely!!!

Comment: My application has more requirements than just the Linphone application from the Playstore ! Thank you.

Comment: Ok. You are writing your SIP phone using Linphone SDK. Well Linphone API is pretty capable.

Comment: Yes ! But I can't run my application because of this error during launch.

Comment: Is this error caused after doing the basic install of the Linphone SDK from the Playstore?

Comment: Yes it is. I've just added the linphone.jar library in the libs folder of my android project. 
I'm able to write code with the Linphone API (with autocompletion etc...) and without error at build.